# Not found exception while getting drawable

Tags: android, exception, drawable, getresource

I am trying to get a drawable but I am getting resource not found exception.
The code is only one line actually but I am getting the same exception.

```
package com.example.tafy.remotebluerc;

import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
    //BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
}
}
```

This is the exception that I am getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.tafy.remotebluerc, PID: 10573
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tafy.remotebluerc/com.example.tafy.remotebluerc.BluetoothActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060055
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060055
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1133)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:708)
                  at com.example.tafy.remotebluerc.BluetoothActivity.onCreate(BluetoothActivity.java:16)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting that exception because I was trying to get v24 drawable.
I solved the problem with using simple drawables.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is come through inflating drawable.
The Exception is

> Resources.NotFoundException

But real exception is may be **`"Binary XML file line #20: invalid color state list tag gradient"`**. 
That is beacuse in api lover 24 not supported gradient.

**Solution**

Duplicate layout and remove gradient tag from layout-v23

If your are using Image view use

> ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_ic)

instead of `ImageView.setImageDrawable`

Answer (score -1):

`getDrawable()` is deprecated, try using:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
```

And Of course, make sure your ic_launcher_foreground exists!

Comment: Are you sure you have a drawable directory and that icon exists?

Comment: @SnkTay no relation to deprecated methods

Comment: I have drawable folder and drawable resource inside the folder

Answer (score -1):

If I'm correct getDrawable() is deprecated and you should be using one of the following

1) `ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.name);`

which will give you a drawable with your activity theme

2) `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.name, null);`

which will give you a drawable without any theme

Also, Make sure you clean and rebuild your project if you haven't done so.

Comment: hun? what does mean? i am using deprecated methods without any problem.

Comment: @Mr.AF It's deprecated for a reason and he shouldn't be using.

Comment: @Ruan_Lopes ya he shouldn't but first he should find his real problem